# Renaming multiple file with continuous number

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I am trying to rename multiple files at once where the condition is to put serial number at around middle point (not exact mid) using batch file. I’m using Windows 8.

From

```
video.mp4  
video_2.mp4  
video_3.mp4  
…  
video_10.mp4  
video_11.mp4
```

To

```
file_01_finished.mp4  
file_02_finished.mp4  
file_03_finished.mp4  
…  
file_10_finished.mp4  
file_11_finished.mp4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ren video.mp4 video_1.mp4
for /F "tokens=2 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B video_*.mp4') do (
   set /A "n=100+%%a"
   ren "video_%%a.mp4" "file_!n:~-2!_finished.mp4"
)
```